# Magento 1.4 - Display All Products

Tags: magento

I have a cms page in magento which I would like to display all products from all categories in.

I found this which described how to do it on 1.3 but this no longer works on 1.4:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/199368/

Remove the "filter" code from Special.php to display all products.

Thanks